# How can I refactor a long if-else statement checking array length?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am writing a program that uses checkboxes to filter a list of items.

I have a group of 3 checkboxes: `phase`, `specialty`, and `type`. Once the checkboxes are marked, they are put into an array which is then used to filter out a list if the conditions match.

When making this, I ran into a few issues:

- If no boxes were checked, then no list would appear at all.
- If a box in all categories were checked, then it would show both conditions rather than when both are true (so if I had phase `Base 1` and specialty `Race` checked, then the list would show all `Race` matches and all `Base 1` matches)
- If a box was not checked but another one was, then nothing would appear since it didn't fit both categories.

To fix all three of these issues, I made an `if, if/else` statement to check the array length of each category. If all arrays (checkboxes) were empty (unchecked), then the original list would appear. If 1 box was checked, but the others weren't, then nothing would break. Etc.. This was made into quite a long statement.

Now, I do plan to add 2-3 more checkbox options, and don't want to complicate things even more. If I keep doing the way that I'm doing now, I may end up with double the current statements I have now.

Currently, the way this list is being filtered is the following, *note, the console.logs are to recognize which condition I am using*:

```
if (phases.length === 0 && specialties.length === 0 && type.length === 0) {
      const workouts = this.workouts;
      this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
    } else if (phases.length > 0 && specialties.length > 0 && type.length > 0) {
      const workouts = this.workouts.filter(
        workout => byPhase(workout) && bySpecialty(workout) && byType(workout)
      );
      this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
      console.log("1 EVERYTHING CHECKED");
    } else if (
      phases.length > 0 &&
      specialties.length > 0 &&
      type.length === 0
    ) {
      const workouts = this.workouts.filter(
        workout => byPhase(workout) && bySpecialty(workout)
      );
      this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
      console.log("2 PHASE AND SPECIALTY (no type)");
    } else if (
      phases.length > 0 &&
      specialties.length === 0 &&
      type.length > 0
    ) {
      const workouts = this.workouts.filter(
        workout => byPhase(workout) && byType(workout)
      );
      this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
      console.log("3 PHASE AND TYPE (no specialty)");
    } else if (
      phases.length > 0 &&
      specialties.length === 0 &&
      type.length === 0
    ) {
      const workouts = this.workouts.filter(workout => byPhase(workout));
      this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
      console.log("4 PHASE ONLY (no type or specialty)");
    } else if (
      phases.length === 0 &&
      specialties.length > 0 &&
      type.length > 0
    ) {
      const workouts = this.workouts.filter(
        workout => bySpecialty(workout) && byType(workout)
      );
      this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
      console.log("5 SPECIALTY AND TYPE (no phase)");
    } else if (
      phases.length === 0 &&
      specialties.length > 0 &&
      type.length === 0
    ) {
      const workouts = this.workouts.filter(workout => bySpecialty(workout));
      this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
      console.log("6 SPECIALTY ONLY (no phase nor type)");
    } else if (
      phases.length === 0 &&
      specialties.length === 0 &&
      type.length > 0
    ) {
      const workouts = this.workouts.filter(workout => byType(workout));
      this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
      console.log("7 TYPE ONLY (no phase nor specialty)");
    }
```

Is there a way to refactor this so I don't continue to add on to the statements, making it an even longer block of code? Or is this not really much of a concern to keep my statement so long?

[Here is the stackblitz to my full project.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jfb7wf?file=src/app/features/workouts-page/workoutservice/workout.service.ts) You can find the `if/else` statements in `src/app/features/workouts-page/workoutservice/workout.service.ts`. The code is found above should be specific enough for this statement.

Thank you.

Comment: You can add the checks directly in the filter callback function, something like this: `(!phases.length || byPhase(workout))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. This uses a single `filter` pass:

```js
filterWorkouts(phases: string[], specialties: string[], types: string[]) {
  const workouts = this.workouts.filter(workout => {
    return (
      (phases.length === 0 || phases.indexOf(workout.phase) >= 0) &&
      (specialties.length === 0 || specialties.indexOf(workout.specialty) >= 0) &&
      (types.length === 0 || types.indexOf(workout.type) >= 0)
    );
  });
  this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
}
```

You would need to add a one-liner for each additional filter is all. Here's a [working implementation on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jfb7wf-oaiwxi?file=src/app/features/workouts-page/workoutservice/workout.service.ts) for you to play around with.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much for such a concise code and a great answer. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Since the `byPhase` and related functions are just functions, you could store them in an array based on the values. Then you could call the functions within the array to pass up to your filter.

```js
function byPhase(workout) { console.log('by phase'); }
function bySpecialty(workout) { console.log('by specialty'); }
function byType(workout) { console.log('by type'); }

// This should filter without specialties
phases = [1,2,3];
specialties = [];
type = [3,4];

const workoutFilters = [
  phases.length > 0 ? byPhase : null,
  specialties.length > 0 ? bySpecialty : null,
  type.length > 0 ? byType: null,
].filter(Boolean);

// Show selected filters
console.log('filters:', workoutFilters);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up accepting the other answer from Dean, but found they both worked out very well. Thanks for opening my eyes to a much better way of doing this and for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can always return from your if to avoid using an else if as long as there isn't something afterwards. In your case, there wasn't so that's one way to shorten things up.

Also, `len === 0` can always be replaced with `!len` as it's a bit more succinct and instead of `len > 0` it can just be `if (len)` if you're comfortable with that, some don't find it as read-able so I'll leave it up to you.

I noticed the same line came after filter op: `this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);` so I moved that to the end and only wrote it once outside of the other blocks to avoid having it run at the end of each block.

Then I noticed that you are basically just trying to use that filter if one of the filters is applied so instead of else if, I used 3 if statements that will apply the filtered param and moved workouts up in scope and gave it its own unique variable so instead of filtering on `this.workouts` you are filtering on the wo in the fn and updating it each time. This way, you don't have to check for the negative conditions as it won't filter them if the condition doesn't apply and will filter again if a second param applies (gives you the && without writing out every condition).

I think this is a very read-able solution that mostly preserves the code you've written so far.

```
 filterWorkouts(phases: string[], specialties: string[], type: string[]) {
    const byPhase = workout => phases.some(phase => workout.phase === phase);
    const bySpecialty = workout =>
      specialties.some(specialty => workout.specialty === specialty);
    const byType = workout => type.some(type => workout.type === type);
    let wo = this.workouts;

    if (phases.length) {
      wo = wo.filter(workout => byPhase(workout));
      console.log("CHECKED PHASE");
    }
    if (specialties.length) {
      wo = wo.filter(workout => bySpecialty(workout));
      console.log("CHECKED SPECIALTY");
    }
    if (type.length) {
      wo = wo.filter(workout => byType(workout));
      console.log("CHECKED TYPE");
    }
    this.selectedWorkouts.next(wo);
    return;
  }
}
```