# Filtering a Nested Array with Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am working on a project where I have a workout list as well as a filter to view a specific selection of the workouts depending on which checkboxes are marked. So far, everything has been working well thanks to a technique solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60083475/11008457) . This technique works great for filtering for individual items, however, when I nest items within the array it no longer works.

Currently, I have a workout model that takes in the following:

```
title,
description,
imagePath,
type: string,
duration,
specialty,
phase,
zwo
```

And I have checkboxes using Angular SelectionModel. These checkboxes are filtering for the following:
`phase`, `specialty`, and `type` using the filter method provided in the link above (this is working as expected):

```
filterWorkouts(phases: string[], specialties: string[], types: string[]) {
  const workouts = this.workouts.filter(workout => {
    return (
      (phases.length === 0 || phases.indexOf(workout.phase) >= 0) &&
      (specialties.length === 0 || specialties.indexOf(workout.specialty) >= 0) &&
      (types.length === 0 || types.indexOf(workout.type) >= 0)
    );
  });
  this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
}
```

I decided there may be cases where I want *multiple* phases. To prepare for this, I created a nested array within the service (in the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jfb7wf-htb71w) this can be found in `features/workouts-page/workoutservice/workout.service`). This nested array takes in the same items from the workout model, with the exception that the phase is a nested array:

```
 workouts: Workout[] = [
    new Workout(
      'title',
      `description...`,
      "..img",
      "type",
      duration,
      "specialty...",
      ["Base 1", "Testing"],
      true/false
    ),
```

Note the `["Base 1", "Testing"]` as this is now a nested array.

The problem is, the filtering method breaks when I make this change. The only way the checkbox filter works is if *no phase is selected*. If I go to the `filterWorkouts()` from above, and in the `return` change the line:

`...  (phases.length === 0 || phases.indexOf(workout.phase) >= 0) && ...`

to: `...  (phases.length === 0 || phases.indexOf(workout.phase[0]) >= 0) && ...`

It works again, but of course only looks for the array with the index of 0.

I have tried looping through the array and checking the index against the filter, but this has broken my app every time.

**Is** there a way to filter my checkboxes against every item in the array rather than only one? So if the `phase` of a workout has `["Base 1", "Race"]` I want it to appear whether Base 1 or Race is checked in the boxes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am happy to clarify anything as well.

[Here is the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-jfb7wf-htb71w) (simplified for ease of use). The service location is mentioned above. The `workouts-filter` and `workouts-list` are coming from two separate components within the `workouts-page` folder.

Comment: Try: `!phases.length || phases.some(phase => workout.phase.includes(phase))`. This condition will be `true` if `phases` is empty or `workout.phase` contains any of its elements. I'm not sure if that is the logic you're looking for.

Comment: Titus, this was perfect and seems to be working great. Thank you so much!! Feel free to put this as the answer if you so desire so I can accept it and so you can get reputation. Thanks again, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a condition like this:

```
!phases.length || phases.some(phase => workout.phase.includes(phase))
```

What this does is to first check if the `phases` array is empty and if it is not, check if any of its elements is present in the `workout.phase` array.